# Mallet Sequence Tagging Feature Vector

Tags: sequence, tagging, mallet

In the [Mallet Sequence Tagging Tutorial](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php) what the feature vector looks like? Why is LOWERCASE not there in the second row? Why does not all the rows  have same number of columns?